# How to display websitname/username after login

Tags: php, authentication

I have no idea how to do this. I have a login system, my client wants me to display the username in the address bar like  -  websitename/username, once the user is logged in...

Comment: I would look in this direction: when a user clicks `Sign In`, on the client side you take the provided user name and submit a login request to `websitename/username`. On the server side you should parse such URL to extract user name, and proceed with authentication from there. Just a rough outline.

Comment: You will not receive an answer if you don't give us more information. If you created a login system it schould be no problem for you to fetch the username of your authenticated user and echo it wherever you want. How did you realized the login?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the username from the session or how to do a url rewrite in .htdocs?

Comment: @developerwjk  exactly... the same ... rewrite .htdocs